# Timing Jitter of Counter Query ... verify hypothesis / noise reduction

Tags: r, time-series, noise

I am measuring traffic on an interface every 5 minutes, but the data platform is having an issue with the SNMP data. I think it is caused by timing jitter ... where the data platform queries the router *approximately* every 5 minutes. All I get is the 5-minute-rounded time stamp and the number of bytes. Therefore, if you'll notice below, I believe the noise in the SNMP data is generally negatively correlated (i.e. it catches up eventually).

The NetFlow data is more precise, but has accuracy (calibration) issues and is generally less reliable (will tend to drop out at key times when the router is busy ... which is the time we care about, there is one each before and after 03:00 UTC in the sample below) ... but it ***is*** available.

In terms of code, I generally work in R and the data is on a PostgreSQL server.

What statistical technique (R function?) would you use to

- Verify the hypothesis
- Correctly recover the SNMP data as I believe that there is additional information below the traditional noise floor.

Thanks.

--Stephen

***Edits:***
As requested, I have grabbed sample data for a day that illustrates the issue:

[image: SNMP vs. Netflow]

***Sample Data***

Note, this is the data in the plot above and provides a good example of what I'm trying to solve.

````
structure(list(obs_time = structure(c(1573084800, 1573085100, 
1573085400, 1573085700, 1573086000, 1573086300, 1573086600, 1573086900, 
1573087200, 1573087500, 1573087800, 1573088100, 1573088400, 1573088700, 
1573089000, 1573089300, 1573089600, 1573089900, 1573090200, 1573090500, 
1573090800, 1573091100, 1573091400, 1573091700, 1573092000, 1573092300, 
1573092600, 1573092900, 1573093200, 1573093500, 1573093800, 1573094100, 
1573094400, 1573094700, 1573095000, 1573095300, 1573095600, 1573095900, 
1573096200, 1573096500, 1573096800, 1573097100, 1573097400, 1573097700, 
1573098000, 1573098300, 1573098600, 1573098900, 1573099200, 1573099500, 
1573099800, 1573100100, 1573100400, 1573100700, 1573101000, 1573101300, 
1573101600, 1573101900, 1573102200, 1573102500, 1573102800, 1573103100, 
1573103400, 1573103700, 1573104000, 1573104300, 1573104600, 1573104900, 
1573105200, 1573105500, 1573105800, 1573106100, 1573106400, 1573106700, 
1573107000, 1573107300, 1573107600, 1573107900, 1573108200, 1573108500, 
1573108800, 1573109100, 1573109400, 1573109700, 1573110000, 1573110300, 
1573110600, 1573110900, 1573111200, 1573111500, 1573111800, 1573112100, 
1573112400, 1573112700, 1573113000, 1573113300, 1573113600, 1573113900, 
1573114200, 1573114500, 1573114800, 1573115100, 1573115400, 1573115700, 
1573116000, 1573116300, 1573116600, 1573116900, 1573117200, 1573117500, 
1573117800, 1573118100, 1573118400, 1573118700, 1573119000, 1573119300, 
1573119600, 1573119900, 1573120200, 1573120500, 1573120800, 1573121100, 
1573121400, 1573121700, 1573122000, 1573122300, 1573122600, 1573122900, 
1573123200, 1573123500, 1573123800, 1573124100, 1573124400, 1573124700, 
1573125000, 1573125300, 1573125600, 1573125900, 1573126200, 1573126500, 
1573126800, 1573127100, 1573127400, 1573127700, 1573128000, 1573128300, 
1573128600, 1573128900, 1573129200, 1573129500, 1573129800, 1573130100, 
1573130400, 1573130700, 1573131000, 1573131300, 1573131600, 1573131900, 
1573132200, 1573132500, 1573132800, 1573133100, 1573133400, 1573133700, 
1573134000, 1573134300, 1573134600, 1573134900, 1573135200, 1573135500, 
1573135800, 1573136100, 1573136400, 1573136700, 1573137000, 1573137300, 
1573137600, 1573137900, 1573138200, 1573138500, 1573138800, 1573139100, 
1573139400, 1573139700, 1573140000, 1573140300, 1573140600, 1573140900, 
1573141200, 1573141500, 1573141800, 1573142100, 1573142400, 1573142700, 
1573143000, 1573143300, 1573143600, 1573143900, 1573144200, 1573144500, 
1573144800, 1573145100, 1573145400, 1573145700, 1573146000, 1573146300, 
1573146600, 1573146900, 1573147200, 1573147500, 1573147800, 1573148100, 
1573148400, 1573148700, 1573149000, 1573149300, 1573149600, 1573149900, 
1573150200, 1573150500, 1573150800, 1573151100, 1573151400, 1573151700, 
1573152000, 1573152300, 1573152600, 1573152900, 1573153200, 1573153500, 
1573153800, 1573154100, 1573154400, 1573154700, 1573155000, 1573155300, 
1573155600, 1573155900, 1573156200, 1573156500, 1573156800, 1573157100, 
1573157400, 1573157700, 1573158000, 1573158300, 1573158600, 1573158900, 
1573159200, 1573159500, 1573159800, 1573160100, 1573160400, 1573160700, 
1573161000, 1573161300, 1573161600, 1573161900, 1573162200, 1573162500, 
1573162800, 1573163100, 1573163400, 1573163700, 1573164000, 1573164300, 
1573164600, 1573164900, 1573165200, 1573165500, 1573165800, 1573166100, 
1573166400, 1573166700, 1573167000, 1573167300, 1573167600, 1573167900, 
1573168200, 1573168500, 1573168800, 1573169100, 1573169400, 1573169700, 
1573170000, 1573170300, 1573170600, 1573170900), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), ingress_bytes_netflow = c(1183660651552, 1180184645200, 
1176146428928, 1195459712560, 1219028072840, 1223522450864, 1238823892936, 
1225063221168, 1242010021840, 1249595163792, 1255561775864, 1240606141968, 
1239362115840, 1238148271280, 1269174379216, 1297769124072, 1295692823360, 
1330700207784, 1298315315192, 1349404081296, 1360137849448, 1397411950016, 
1395005459696, 1413966318064, 1336976902880, 1338529356784, 1230700237608, 
1210538516032, 1334643629728, 1326601713008, 1396908032288, 1448056190736, 
1525733411896, 1517866348864, 1467455547256, 1443247846232, 1478102861520, 
1559735798704, 1565433523144, 1577881955880, 1522622288560, 1504906718792, 
1445177410832, 1527588081232, 1539521688560, 1590190525648, 1665075271952, 
1667839949064, 1659255393160, 1625756772392, 1686485159040, 1693604334016, 
1695759214616, 1716476595992, 1711218903232, 1718828078888, 1713015904752, 
1714162090424, 1673049068320, 1672054421800, 1633134912152, 1657057319808, 
1642899979056, 1640532560672, 1617558067880, 1607391017128, 1590462777280, 
1569105260784, 1522612722560, 1512452131640, 1480254311560, 1444581132576, 
1416584506464, 1375669999728, 1357356644856, 1330652241768, 1294873413416, 
1246783576296, 1221703254224, 1177809700464, 1151921311616, 1111441741624, 
1078638446528, 1028846994496, 991255441848, 963597903512, 924670799544, 
895871852416, 858446844144, 819316679728, 786583961016, 761104300208, 
731816582008, 692813600784, 672324718640, 637112485392, 610495772912, 
590828319512, 567184015600, 541930612192, 514693968824, 495454539600, 
477938999064, 459465181728, 443509743864, 431561094648, 418781388848, 
396938498608, 377237749464, 365873680288, 353160476288, 341785583648, 
333596544536, 318036540544, 306237887624, 294391021904, 283797793896, 
276402870632, 267712704736, 261824712856, 255019556480, 248691462064, 
245476386144, 236784455480, 235133409112, 226328116032, 225460512936, 
222773838768, 219390057064, 213534761184, 211706815712, 209858124128, 
213451073064, 213112988416, 216665471232, 218157292880, 218322819080, 
218626251688, 222673767840, 226880933472, 226204559688, 228075500008, 
234510115768, 238669623936, 255671756624, 262800909480, 272932768856, 
280349294288, 292759204976, 299808707720, 314074006064, 329200472664, 
336957291296, 352772962768, 372092539816, 378253769312, 420850730496, 
446903186032, 475753704808, 490341598520, 507391494840, 515115891280, 
554326540200, 571833771120, 590900883352, 625870836832, 647502218104, 
671669559080, 726533207048, 767607032872, 794253067712, 821009093464, 
845967661808, 870133078304, 898076334992, 914790775392, 942212574400, 
952196759288, 966922273264, 969023347568, 1010886989392, 1016697745024, 
1028500627616, 1004827205928, 1026039415296, 1022657220496, 1027227383776, 
1009522086256, 1004181850200, 997021158120, 994276166632, 1022828259040, 
1020795366592, 1007996245552, 994222167128, 995312177184, 977107478632, 
976161969632, 966747244472, 947203891488, 982789860432, 968343320056, 
957959911672, 949543451328, 967879810144, 958308556736, 962461413192, 
943428345640, 938742747328, 952037149160, 927766320552, 928720713392, 
914657922104, 926660939512, 905111115472, 905286856624, 916277111392, 
911813861752, 932654853144, 898735006976, 899364206392, 887550733224, 
877340125008, 888306121560, 893089421096, 880778946336, 881725463184, 
894971677496, 881769828960, 884894746728, 896583482600, 883861786496, 
884127167352, 875578218152, 872893868456, 896385072360, 887989463592, 
877706154448, 883356919344, 888420553816, 876998827776, 873031013536, 
883468103448, 885305815560, 906933398256, 905374267824, 907345270352, 
897225395664, 913773211112, 908028244416, 931589987424, 917374244320, 
926354824744, 932277310768, 924656872992, 915470763320, 923979276376, 
919167826448, 919179790904, 928064421272, 968544206160, 947880255880, 
965274402048, 966333879992, 955326228336, 952864832568, 949444780016, 
956577162376, 968604787984, 992767680392, 998489356480, 1006623586808, 
1005946556472, 1009329299088, 1034388000776, 1041385319872, 1056946833312, 
1043407459104, 1078347223896, 1093353663104, 1096377283536, 1132022642408, 
1148999868744, 1163847294232, 1172304392752, 1174757625288, 1213383736568, 
1224601220792), ingress_bytes_snmp = c(1035804737536, 1247565185024, 
1165840613376, 1230212825088, 1205197996032, 1249967996928, 1241348440064, 
1234745556992, 1247349571584, 1213303095296, 1268541685760, 1267761152000, 
1360466018304, 1146550091776, 1199970189312, 1445594136576, 1218641264640, 
1336014012416, 1348492853248, 1542517030912, 1234957893632, 1349272207360, 
1434522615808, 1301758214144, 1592193712128, 1485875970048, 1469678747648, 
1301428043776, 1413630656512, 1657656442880, 1338931937280, 1629437952000, 
1503126749184, 1297859215360, 1810977914880, 1391443443712, 1569535950848, 
1438857297920, 1847430610944, 1603953623040, 1473028161536, 1513652617216, 
1763931586560, 1684451622912, 1590493315072, 1710715437056, 1864378089472, 
1490819874816, 1706199351296, 1771485921280, 1583291957248, 1599416565760, 
1958613745664, 1437283123200, 1673588506624, 1795257925632, 1671604994048, 
1726894833664, 1963109253120, 1449800499200, 1569650507776, 1872794222592, 
1764544741376, 1363936149504, 1754627571712, 1455636217856, 1687975886848, 
1615085830144, 1412955111424, 1635180871680, 1589479997440, 1448168521728, 
1355204132864, 1167406530560, 1352850604032, 1295379070976, 1438364991488, 
1238811541504, 1203045400576, 1100358877184, 1220304044032, 1028244570112, 
1080534171648, 1186094776320, 834297790464, 941559513088, 928178569216, 
905753853952, 920393940992, 828434743296, 773290262528, 656736256000, 
705491107840, 656482762752, 701610983424, 645953552384, 678417399808, 
522483564544, 559148630016, 536863834112, 522913873920, 527871279104, 
471568121856, 411253702656, 435252068352, 409065684992, 447574016000, 
366460272640, 437653307392, 307012370432, 389954863104, 305919000576, 
308627439616, 340120272896, 300639813632, 299548704768, 271130116096, 
255551815680, 287329189888, 267001626624, 245751644160, 280184684544, 
220743974912, 252977037312, 187360657408, 229232295936, 265467805696, 
219574583296, 174907719680, 209880399872, 250904657920, 189729357824, 
206369767424, 215069917184, 216703811584, 214718562304, 231380189184, 
209283366912, 237871693824, 223946833920, 226721005568, 230408929280, 
253461381120, 205032685568, 291760177152, 248654315520, 269101432832, 
256052789248, 350820925440, 271524937728, 310350118912, 324503076864, 
357122310144, 337737449472, 397392543744, 380424814592, 420442079232, 
462573797376, 474452623360, 485258493952, 489759113216, 592373940224, 
459643355136, 619332173824, 570410729472, 670635065344, 646476857344, 
670558060544, 797950935040, 751194996736, 781238599680, 819846774784, 
860986605568, 939772280832, 810628022272, 844643106816, 1054746542080, 
934065733632, 930055979008, 1111658201088, 896055640064, 1033070051328, 
1026613182464, 1013568176128, 1031098925056, 1098882416640, 1027634692096, 
901913575424, 1082688012288, 817838882816, 1158169624576, 824367316992, 
1081317785600, 1042632671232, 910080147456, 1002217340928, 1063135150080, 
978357583872, 971585683456, 987818688512, 973628440576, 966792511488, 
1029984616448, 854868426752, 915844628480, 961907589120, 985828491264, 
894861180928, 942299873280, 1100765855744, 840747515904, 865150435328, 
881218093056, 1032182562816, 907285823488, 901700059136, 976576446464, 
785035493376, 983674650624, 995818995712, 895848611840, 763681701888, 
978883051520, 707119677440, 997226905600, 830101585920, 856880578560, 
972942934016, 940385566720, 835295117312, 827471953920, 1022970494976, 
808010645504, 862408540160, 836354899968, 854578692096, 962767355904, 
962012839936, 773286461440, 916120731648, 785680105472, 916430061568, 
868019273728, 979745964032, 910665711616, 970438803456, 805623103488, 
973580075008, 822254370816, 870270500864, 1047191814144, 827951808512, 
928731234304, 931164258304, 921669009408, 828690595840, 953459933184, 
1060348166144, 789327642624, 900563992576, 1085421322240, 876563529728, 
1040543186944, 961790279680, 964872503296, 944735518720, 954545209344, 
855077289984, 987037040640, 947300139008, 1030453460992, 996268244992, 
1090786099200, 934113640448, 1044237058048, 984172331008, 1033782755328, 
1147247001600, 1045838495744, 1148862726144, 1201239621632, 1013101756416, 
1259201495040, 973399064576, 1348800086016, 1073572151296, 1149437739008, 
1280313524224)), row.names = c(NA, -288L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))```
````

Comment: What is the hypothesis you want to verify? What is SNMP? What does your data actually look like? Can you post a sample? I can't really offer much advice without knowing the above....

Comment: The hypothesis I'm trying to verify is if timing jitter is indeed the cause (i.e. one jump up is made up for over the next several periods) ... I'm not seeing how to post data ... would i need to add a GitHub link or something similar with a .csv?

Comment: You can take a dataframe (or a subset if you prefer) and put it into a text form easily read in R using the `dput()` function. Alternatively, you can make some fake data up although this is a little more time consuming.

Comment: Thanks fo the `dput()` tip ... I have edited the question appropriately with a sample of the data with the behavior I'm looking at.